# custom TransactionManger set is not working for spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am very new to spring boot and batch. 
we are trying integrate spring batch into our existing spring boot REST application to add capabilities to persist data from csv files into oracle database.

I tried to configure datasource and transactionManager in my  BatchConfiguration file by extending BatchConfigurer as shown below. I am calling a service method to persist data to DB in IteamProcessor. but the job is failing with below exception. Can you please help me to troubleshoot this issue and guide me in ow to set the existing datasource and Transaction Manager in spring batch?

```
2019-05-13 11:14:51,689 LL="ERROR" source=batchprocessor CR="" RE="" DE="" TR="scheduling-1" LN="o.s.b.c.s.AbstractStep"    MSG=Encountered an error executing step process-consumers-step in job consumers-batch-loader
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: transactionManager,customTransactionManager
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1139)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:407)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:284)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at com.sample.batchprocessor.model.ConsumerWhitelistService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8061a132.updateWhitelist(<generated>)
        at com.sample.batchprocessor.config.Processor.process(Processor.java:50)
        at com.sample.batchprocessor.config.Processor.process(Processor.java:1)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:129)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:205)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:203)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:399)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sample.batchprocessor.config.BatchJobLauncher.load(BatchJobLauncher.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-13 11:14:51,722 LL="INFO" source=batchprocessor CR="" RE="" DE="" TR="scheduling-1" LN="o.s.b.c.l.s.SimpleJobLauncher"    MSG=Job: [SimpleJob: [name=consumers-batch-loader]] completed with the following parameters: [{Time=1557771291413}] and the following status: [FAILED]
```

Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BatchConfiguration implements BatchConfigurer {

    private JobRepository jobRepository;
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier("customEntityManagerFactory")
    EntityManagerFactoryBean merchantEntityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("customTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
        return this.jobRepository;
    }   

    @Override
    public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        return this.jobLauncher;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the **full** stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: thanks for your response @MahmoudBenHassine. I have added full stacktrace to the original question

Comment: Your `BatchConfiguration` is not complete, do you have a getter for the transaction manager there? Looks like there is a bean is looking for a single transaction manager but there are two transaction managers and spring is unable to know which one to inject. Please provide more details about your config to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your configuration is incomplete. I can see you are implementing BatchConfigurer for creating a custom repository.

Here is some sample code that helps you to  understand what is missing in your configuration

```
//Data source configuration for H2
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder embeddedDatabaseBuilder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return embeddedDatabaseBuilder
            .addScript("classpath:employee.sql") // Add your sqlscripts in properties
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .build();
}

//creating JobRepository
@Override
public JobRepository getJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setTransactionManager(getTransactionManager());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return  factory.getObject();
}


@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws Exception {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Override
public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(getJobRepository());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Override
public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() throws Exception {
    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.